# Is the libc++fs.a file corrupt in deb http://llvm.org/apt/stretch/ llvm-toolchain-stretch-7 main

Tags: libc++

When I do a `nm /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libc++fs.a` I get:

```
...
nm: /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libc++fs.a(operations.cpp.o): SHT_GROUP section [index 46] has no SHF_GROUP sections
nm: operations.cpp.o: File format not recognized
...
```

The exact version I have is 1:7.0.1~svn348686-1~exp1~20181211133235.57.
Is this package known to be corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the new version 1:7.0.1~svn348686-1~exp1~20190111074544.62 is correct with a libc++fs.a file that is possible to get correct result for `nm`.

So I just had to do an `apt remove libc++-7-dev` and then a `apt install libc++-7-dev` to get the new version.